# Puppeteer Delete Navigator.Webdriver

Tags: selenium, automation, puppeteer, browser-automation

I m using puppeteer for scraping.
I can pass navigator.webdriver property= false but i need to delete that prop completely.

https://bot.sannysoft.com/

I tried with passing false to navigator.webdriver. This trick can pass on 
https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html

but in https://bot.sannysoft.com/ cant.

here is webpage testing bot. This test is looking for are there any "webdriver" prop in navigator object. Doesn't care if its true or false.
 I need to remove this webdriver prop from browser.

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: not yet, waiting for a friend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403652/2440

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
const newProto = navigator.__proto__;
delete newProto.webdriver;
navigator.__proto__ = newProto;
```

Comment: why not define to false insted of delete it?

Comment: @Matrix because in normal browsers this is not defined.

Comment: here for example: page.evaluateOnNewDocument(pageFunction[, ...args]); your code should be inside "pageFunction"

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, I'll leave an answer:

I had the same question, and @Nodarius's answer worked for me.
Since you didn't accept it, I assume your problem is still persisting.

This is probably because, even if you run in, you need that code to run before the page loads (or before the website accesses the variable).

I achieved this using a proxy (https://mitmproxy.org/) which loads the script before the page loads.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
  window.navigator = {}
})
```

Comment: will try this asap

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DQCvyuHM This is what I am doing, everything works except the WebGL Vendor which doesn't work on chrome normally anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, "webdriver", {
      get: () => false,
    });
});
```