# Selenium triggering CAPTCHA?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to scrape this website using selenium (geckodriver) in python. The website started giving me a catpcha after a while. The captcha is triggered when I use a browser launched by selenium, even when loading my personal Firefox profile. However, it is not triggered when I use a browser I manually launch with the same profile. Any insight into what might be going on?

Comment: If you slow down the operation rate (like how many requests you are running per minute) does it affect it?

Comment: There are ways that websites can detect Selenium usage. If you google some, you'll find some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040904/10413416
can give you more info how exactly browsers understand selenium is running and depending on the browser, there is algorithms that trigger check on suspicious activity.