# Why are the contents of robots.txt different when accessed manually and through ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver, robots.txt

I'm trying to respect the robots.txt file, while webcrawling, and I encountered something weird. The the robots.txt URL I'm trying to access is: https://podatki.gov.si/robots.txt

If I open this link in Chrome, I get this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But if I open this link with Internet Explorer or Selenium WebDriver (ChromeDriver), I get this:

```
#
# robots.txt
#
# This file is to prevent the crawling and indexing of certain parts
# of your site by web crawlers and spiders run by sites like Yahoo!
# and Google. By telling these "robots" where not to go on your site,
# you save bandwidth and server resources.
#
# This file will be ignored unless it is at the root of your host:
# Used:    http://example.com/robots.txt
# Ignored: http://example.com/site/robots.txt
#
# For more information about the robots.txt standard, see:
# http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
# CSS, JS, Images
Allow: /misc/*.css$
Allow: /misc/*.css?
Allow: /misc/*.js$
Allow: /misc/*.js?
Allow: /misc/*.gif
Allow: /misc/*.jpg
Allow: /misc/*.jpeg
Allow: /misc/*.png
Allow: /modules/*.css$
Allow: /modules/*.css?
Allow: /modules/*.js$
Allow: /modules/*.js?
Allow: /modules/*.gif
Allow: /modules/*.jpg
Allow: /modules/*.jpeg
Allow: /modules/*.png
Allow: /profiles/*.css$
Allow: /profiles/*.css?
Allow: /profiles/*.js$
Allow: /profiles/*.js?
Allow: /profiles/*.gif
Allow: /profiles/*.jpg
Allow: /profiles/*.jpeg
Allow: /profiles/*.png
Allow: /themes/*.css$
Allow: /themes/*.css?
Allow: /themes/*.js$
Allow: /themes/*.js?
Allow: /themes/*.gif
Allow: /themes/*.jpg
Allow: /themes/*.jpeg
Allow: /themes/*.png
# Directories
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /misc/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /profiles/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /themes/
# Files
Disallow: /CHANGELOG.txt
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /INSTALL.mysql.txt
Disallow: /INSTALL.pgsql.txt
Disallow: /INSTALL.sqlite.txt
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /INSTALL.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /MAINTAINERS.txt
Disallow: /update.php
Disallow: /UPGRADE.txt
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /comment/reply/
Disallow: /filter/tips/
Disallow: /node/add/
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /user/register/
Disallow: /user/password/
Disallow: /user/login/
Disallow: /user/logout/
# Paths (no clean URLs)
Disallow: /?q=admin/
Disallow: /?q=comment/reply/
Disallow: /?q=filter/tips/
Disallow: /?q=node/add/
Disallow: /?q=search/
Disallow: /?q=user/password/
Disallow: /?q=user/register/
Disallow: /?q=user/login/
Disallow: /?q=user/logout/
```

Why does this happen? The latter seems to be a generic robots.txt file, maybe something autogenerated?

Comment: I opened it in chrome and got the larger one.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the same behavior as follows:

- When accessed the webpage `https://podatki.gov.si/robots.txt` *manually*, I got:

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /
  ```
- When accessed the webpage `https://podatki.gov.si/robots.txt` using *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome*, I got:

  ```
  #
  # robots.txt
  #
  # This file is to prevent the crawling and indexing of certain parts
  # of your site by web crawlers and spiders run by sites like Yahoo!
  # and Google. By telling these "robots" where not to go on your site,
  # you save bandwidth and server resources.
  #
  # This file will be ignored unless it is at the root of your host:
  # Used:    http://example.com/robots.txt
  # Ignored: http://example.com/site/robots.txt
  #
  # For more information about the robots.txt standard, see:
  # http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

  User-agent: *
  Crawl-delay: 10
  # CSS, JS, Images
  Allow: /misc/*.css$
  Allow: /misc/*.css?
  Allow: /misc/*.js$
  Allow: /misc/*.js?
  Allow: /misc/*.gif
  Allow: /misc/*.jpg
  Allow: /misc/*.jpeg
  Allow: /misc/*.png
  Allow: /modules/*.css$
  Allow: /modules/*.css?
  Allow: /modules/*.js$
  Allow: /modules/*.js?
  Allow: /modules/*.gif
  Allow: /modules/*.jpg
  Allow: /modules/*.jpeg
  Allow: /modules/*.png
  Allow: /profiles/*.css$
  Allow: /profiles/*.css?
  Allow: /profiles/*.js$
  Allow: /profiles/*.js?
  Allow: /profiles/*.gif
  Allow: /profiles/*.jpg
  Allow: /profiles/*.jpeg
  Allow: /profiles/*.png
  Allow: /themes/*.css$
  Allow: /themes/*.css?
  Allow: /themes/*.js$
  Allow: /themes/*.js?
  Allow: /themes/*.gif
  Allow: /themes/*.jpg
  Allow: /themes/*.jpeg
  Allow: /themes/*.png
  # Directories
  Disallow: /includes/
  Disallow: /misc/
  Disallow: /modules/
  Disallow: /profiles/
  Disallow: /scripts/
  Disallow: /themes/
  # Files
  Disallow: /CHANGELOG.txt
  Disallow: /cron.php
  Disallow: /INSTALL.mysql.txt
  Disallow: /INSTALL.pgsql.txt
  Disallow: /INSTALL.sqlite.txt
  Disallow: /install.php
  Disallow: /INSTALL.txt
  Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
  Disallow: /MAINTAINERS.txt
  Disallow: /update.php
  Disallow: /UPGRADE.txt
  Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
  # Paths (clean URLs)
  Disallow: /admin/
  Disallow: /comment/reply/
  Disallow: /filter/tips/
  Disallow: /node/add/
  Disallow: /search/
  Disallow: /user/register/
  Disallow: /user/password/
  Disallow: /user/login/
  Disallow: /user/logout/
  # Paths (no clean URLs)
  Disallow: /?q=admin/
  Disallow: /?q=comment/reply/
  Disallow: /?q=filter/tips/
  Disallow: /?q=node/add/
  Disallow: /?q=search/
  Disallow: /?q=user/password/
  Disallow: /?q=user/register/
  Disallow: /?q=user/login/
  Disallow: /?q=user/logout/
  ```

---

### robots.txt

As per [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) website owners use the `robots.txt` file to give instructions about their site to web robots. This is called **The Robots Exclusion Protocol**.

It works as follows:

- A robot wants to vist a website URL, e.g. `http://www.example.com/welcome.html`.
- Before it does so, it firsts checks for http://www.example.com/robots.txt, and finds:

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /
  ```

  - The **`User-agent: *`** means this section applies to all robots.
  - The **`Disallow: /`** tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.

There are two important considerations when using `robots.txt`:

- Robots can ignore your `robots.txt`. Specially malware robots that scan the web for security vulnerabilities, and email address harvesters used by spammers will pay no attention.
- The `robots.txt` file is a publicly available file. Anyone can see what sections of your server you don't want robots to use.

---

### Outro

As using *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* the `navigator.webdriver` defines a standard way for co-operating *user agents* to inform the document that it is controlled by *WebDriver*, so that alternate code paths can be triggered during automation. Hence you are able to see more contents from the `robots.txt`.

You can find a relevant discussion in [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your conclusion. The browser and selenium driver are only retrieving the robots.txt file, not doing anything else. So you can't say that the robots.txt file is ignored. They retrieve it, but it's different in some cases. That's what my problem is.

Comment: @kozeljko Checkout my answer update and let me know your thoughts