# How to bypass "Checking your browser before accessing site" with Firefox in Robot Framework (Selenium Library)?

Tags: selenium, firefox, robotframework, selenium-firefoxdriver

With Robot Framework and its Selenium Library, I need to open *specifically* Firefox, get to a repository on GitLab and download a certain file. Please don't question the tool choice, I was asked to do this with Robot on Firefox and I have to do it with Robot on Firefox. Nothing crazy on the surface actually, but I found out that GitLab runs a "check" on the browser and apparently Selenium gets stuck.

I've searched for solutions, but they all apply to either Selenium on Java, Python, etc., and most of them are about Chrome. Only a handful of unclear ones talk about Firefox and none about Robot with Selenium. I've tried to adapt some of them, such as [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60626696/11216297):

```
SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser    browser=firefox 
... ff_profile_dir=set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled","false");set_preference("useAutomationExtension","false")
SeleniumLibrary.Go To       ${UrlGitLab}
```

But it doesn't work. It's still stuck on the page

> Checking your browser before accessing gitlab.com.
>
> This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your
> requested content shortly.
>
> Please allow up to 5 seconds…

It looks like it tries to reload (?) a couple of times, but it won't go further.

Is there a solution, or a workaround that doesn't completely ditch Robot + Selenium with Firefox?