# Prevent selenium detection on firefox (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automation, geckodriver

To make automation I use selenium on geckodriver (because I can't send emojis by send keys on chrome) but I am actually trying to prevent selenium detection to avoid quick blocks on websites that are highly advanced in noticing bots (social medias for example).

But I have not found any code that really worked for geckodriver. I have searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122151/exclude-switches-in-firefox-webdriver-options) but nothing works (or indeed I don't think so because the little robot logo is still on the firefox url bar).

So does anyone have an idea about how to fix it ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: show us what you have done so far, what errors do you get?. go through this => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example