# Spoof navigator properties in chrome selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, navigator, spoof

I am trying to automate some tasks on a website using chrome selenium. I spoof the `navigator.webdriver` based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040904/3559420). How to spoof other properties of navigator like: `deviceMemory, hardwareConcurrency, maxTouchPoints`? I am using Selenium in C#.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["source"] = "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', { get: () => undefined })"
    };
    var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"c:\bin\", options);
    driver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", parameters);
```

Answer is tested by me and inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405966/3997521.

Answer (score 1):

You can set those before script execution similarly with cdp command. I'm not sure what it looks like in c# but in python:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'deviceMemory', {
      get: () => 99
    })
  """
})
```

Comment: chrome devtools protocol