# Webscraping : How to parse this kind of contents in Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, request

I'm working on a web scraping project

When i run my code :

```
url = myurl

session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url)
print(response.content)
```

The response.content looks like this:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><script>function i700(){}i700.F20=function (){return typeof i700.O20.p60==='function'?i700.O20.p60.apply(i700.O20,arguments):i700.O20.p60;};i700.X70=function (){return typeof i700.v70.p60.............................
```

Inspecting the source webpage using Firefox Dev Tools, I found the data I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reserches, i found the solution.
I noticed that my target website can detect  Selenium as bot, even though there's no automation applied.

So, to access this kind of web page without getting detected, i found a solution using the ChromeOptions() class to add some arguments to:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) 
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

Source: 
[Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Answer (score 0):

The response that you showed does not appear to be gziped; `response.content` will return the response as a [binary byte-string](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BytesStr), which is likely not what you want.

In order to get the response in plain-text, you will want to use `response.text`. From there, you should be able to search the string for the element that you want using [`string.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Source: [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

Comment: Thanks Drew, i  tried your solution, but `response.text` produces the same output of `response.content` . This source seems not to be a binary byte-string, it looks like a compressed javascript functions. When i visit the site with a standard browser,  "source html" looks ok.  When i try to get it from requests library or Selenium, the source looks weird.