# How to scrape the Javascript based site https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings using Selenium and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, akamai

I am trying to get earning dates from https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings 
The site has a javascript loader that loads the earnings table,
but when I am using selenium it is not appears.
I tried chrome and firefox drivers.

a sample of the code:

```
firefox_driver_path = os.path.abspath('../firefoxdriver_win32/geckodriver.exe')
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefox_driver_path, options=options)
driver.get("https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings")
```

how can I get the data?

Answer (score 1):

I took your code added a few tweaks and ran a test to extract the earning dates from https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.dateselect_menu_h_table tr > th > span"))).text)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='dateselect_menu_h_table']//tr/th/span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

---

### Observation

Similar to your observation, I have hit the same roadblock that using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) the earnings table doesn't loads:

[image: marketchameleon]

---

### Deep Dive

While inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the *webpage* I found that some of the `<script>` and other tags refers to the keyword **akam**. As an example:

- `!function(){if(BOOMR=a.BOOMR||{},BOOMR.plugins=BOOMR.plugins||{},!BOOMR.plugins.AK){var e=""=="true"?1:0,t="",n="gertvyrrfrzvsxxfd3ta-f-81b1f5d51-clientnsv4-s.akamaihd.net"`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://marketchameleon.com/akam/11/4e7414cb" defer=""></script>`
- `<noscript><img src="https://marketchameleon.com/akam/11/pixel_4e7414cb?a=dD03OTIxZTlmM2QwMWVhMDkxODhjNzQwN2E3NmFkNzRiMDQ5ODBkOGU0JmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" /></noscript>`
- `<link id="dnsprefetchlink" rel="dns-prefetch" href="//gertvyrrfrzvsxxfd3ta-f-81b1f5d51-clientnsv4-s.akamaihd.net">`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by [**Bot Manager**](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/security/bot-manager.jsp) an advanced bot detection service provided by [**Akamai**](https://www.akamai.com/) and the response gets **blocked**.

---

### Bot Manager

As per the article [Bot Manager - Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf):

[image: akamai_detection]

---

### Conclusion

So it can be concluded that the request for the data is detected as being performed by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance and the response is blocked.

---

### References

A couple of documentations:

- [Bot Manager](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/product-brief/bot-manager-product-brief.pdf)
- [Bot Manager : Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf)

---

### tl; dr

A couple of relevant discussions:

- [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Comment: Thanks! FWIW, I only need `options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')` to get around bot detection for marketchameleon.com.