# Webpage Detecting Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings but the website is blocking selenium. It initially loads into the website, but the earnings calendar script does not load. If I try refreshing the page, I get a "Access Denied You don't have permission" error.  I have tried changing User Agent and other chrome options, but the same issue persists. Can anyone let me know how to bypass the detection?

```py
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings')
```

Comment: Do you need to perform some action like clicking inside the site ? If not, you can just use BeautifulSoup for scraping. It doesn't depend on a chromedriver and probably wouldn't be blocked.

Comment: I need to switch from Show 25 Entries to Show All Entries to grab all the rows. I tried using Requests and BeautifulSoup earlier but it would just hang on requests.get(page), although if there are other options to grab the entire table, I would be open to it.

Comment: It's a good place to start. It'd be much simpler without Selenium.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Comment: Have you read all 19 answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver

Comment: Requests + BS4 might not work because I have to wait for the script tag on the "widget" to load. 
I tried replacing CDC_ with random characters using a Hex editor, but it didn't work. Also tried adding all the suggested options in the thread, but still running into same issue. I will try injecting JS a little later. Thanks.

Comment: Does the discussion [How to scrape the Javascript based site https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353469/how-to-scrape-the-javascript-based-site-https-marketchameleon-com-calendar-ear/62364975#62364975) help you?

Comment: That does help but I'm not too sure how to bypass it. I might just look for a manual work around (Downloading CSV or using a macro) since the solutions I have tried thsu far haven't worked and I only need the data on a daily basis. Thanks!