# How to prevent detection with Selenium in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm beginner of selenium. I have a question is How to prevent detection by some websites such as google, youtube using Java?

Comment: Refer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191) help you?