# How to find the $cdc_ (chromedriver params) in website?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

About this post: [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Some website could detect chromedriver using $cdc_xxxxxxxxxx.

I have ever found this parameter on website through Chrome DevTools (maybe document,network,etc.) when I used selenium to open browser.

But I forgot where it appeared.

I want to know how the website get this parameters of chromedriver?

Answer (score 0):

The question [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) doesn't mentions about **$cdc_xxxxxxxxxx** anyway. However there are a couple of answers which does refers to **`$cdc_xxxxxxxxxx`**

From the answers referring to `$cdc_xxxxxxxxxx` it is quite apperant it is a variable within [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) executable code and *Chromium* / *ChromeDriver* team will be in the best position to answer about the usage of this variable.

---

### Selenium perspective

As far as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is concerned:

> - *Selenium automates browsers. That's it!*
> - *What you do with that power is entirely up to you.*

Finally, I would recommend you, instead of looking into the `$cdc_xxxxxxxxxx` variable you can look at some other aspects like, the [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) or the [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) interface. You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to prevent selenium selenium detection (your answer in another post is helpful). But I want to know how did the website detect with $cdc_?

Comment: @Yun can you post the link for how you successfully detect Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

That is quite simple.

```js
function getCDC(){ 
    let matches = []
    for(let prop in window) {
       prop.match(/cdc_[a-z0-9]/ig) && matches.push(prop)
    }
    return matches 
}
```

[image]