# Selenium stuck on "Checking your browser before accessing URL"

Tags: python, selenium

This is a recent problem, it began I think three or four days ago. It is not isolated to my own system, as I was running the software on a remote server as well (Windows 10, Windows Server). It is not also not isolated to any specific URL, as I can't get past any URL that has this check now.

> Title: "Just a moment..." "Checking your browser before accessing
> URL".  "This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your
> requested content shortly." "Please allow up to 5 seconds..." "DDos
> Protection by Cloudflare" "Ray Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

- I've attempted different systems (both windows based)
- I've attempted different drivers (gecko and chrome)
- I've attempted different urls

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('wwww.etherdelta.com')
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this; or is it time to put poor ol' timmy (the program) down?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @RenéMartínez Yes, the accepted answer, provided by user MrTiny works. Don't forget to modify the driver first.

Comment: At this point, the answer by user MrTiny no longer seems to work (for some sites), I am not sure what has changed.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue with firefox. I was able to solve it by switching to Chrome. 
Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "<WEBSITE>"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

"--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled" hides the "navigator.webdriver" flag.
See [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/60403652#60403652)

**Edit**

You also have to change some default variables of chromedriver. 
Example with perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's/cdc_/dog_/g' /path/to/chromedriver
```

For more details look at the original post. 
See [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108199/14542234)

**Edit 2**

Cloudflare keeps adjusting their algorithm so you could try to use [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) instead of the manual changing of the chromedriver.

[undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) is an optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which should not trigger anti-bot services. It automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

Wether this will work or not kinda depends on the website and the current state of the development. Cloudflare seems to track the development of [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver).

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
url = "<WEBSITE>"
driver= uc.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked well
It even worked for C# SELENIUM

Comment: getting `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` after perl script

Comment: This answer stopped working a few days ago on some of the sites I'm using selenium for. Uncertain what has changed/caused it.

Comment: I gave the undetected-chromedriver a go, but it, unfortunately, got stuck at the same Cloudflare protection stage.

Comment: I fing love you <333

Comment: @gloomyfit try without using ChromeOptions

Answer (score 3):

Try using yout chrome data folder

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

# Configure browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\daria\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

chromedriver = ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.GOOGLE, 
                                            log_level='0', 
                                            print_first_line=False).install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, 
                                options=options,
                                service_log_path=None)

input ("End?")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is crazy... this actually works! But why...????

Comment: It seems because it will run you default Chrome installation, but still unclear why.

Comment: It seems to work on some sites, but doesn't work on others.

Comment: @Mecanik reading your chrome data, like cookies and history, the page detect that you are a bot (you are uring selenium).
Then, using the default chrome folder, selenium will open your chrome window with all you data (user account, history, cookies, etc) and in this way the page think that you are a real user.

Comment: @gloomyfit There can be many reasons why a website is blocking you: IP blocking, cookies, behavior within the website, excessive number of requests in a short time, etc.
Every website needs its own web scraping code.

Comment: This works amazing well. Saved me a lot of time trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when using headless Selenium on a Docker Linux image.

I solved it by creating a virtualdisplay right before calling the webdriver:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
display.start()
```

**Don't forget** to install both pyvirtualdisplay and xvfb:
`pip install pyvirtualdisplay` and `sudo apt-get install xvfb`

And **you must remove the "headless" option** in ChromeDriver, here is the complete code I use :

```
    #Display in order to avoid CloudFare bot detection
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
    display.start()
  
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('enable-automation')
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
```

Since it was working nicely without headless on my local computer, I figured emulate a real display might do the work aswell.
I do not really understand why, but from what I've understood, CloudFare tries to execute javascript code in order to confirm you're not a bot. Having a emulated webpage display helps to do so.

Comment: An interesting suggestion, but, in my case I wasn't even running it headless, to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the browser uses `cloudfare` to protect itself from `DDOS (Distributed Denial Of Service) Attacks`. There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Use `time.sleep` -- if it takes 5 seconds for the webpage to load, just use `time.sleep(5)`.
2. Use `WebDriverWait` -- for example, a `button` with `id` "sample-btn" appears only after this screen. Then what u can do is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'sample-btn'))) #Web driver waits for 10 seconds until element is visible
```

The 2nd one is recommended. But if the 2nd one doesn't work for u, then go with the first one. Hope that this helps!

Comment: I appreciate your contribution, unfortunately, neither approach works. See, even if I kill the program (while keeping the browser open), I can't manually load any of these pages myself (just stuck at the same place). Further confirmed by opening additional tabs that are not at any point controlled by selenium that also remains stuck. Any browser that was not initiated by Selenium works normal though.

Comment: try using headers and user-agents

Comment: Adding a user-agent did not work. Unsure what you mean regarding adding headers to Selenium.