# Checking your browser before accessing message while accessing an application using ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare

I am trying to automate a certain type of routine and it was going all well until the website started performing the "Checking browser..." process (snapshot below). Strangely, it didn't do it during previous runs.

I have tried the following code, which I "stole" from this answer: [*Selenium stuck on “Checking your browser before accessing URL”*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165726/selenium-stuck-on-checking-your-browser-before-accessing-url), but my browser is still unresponsive:

```
url= "URL"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver_new = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe", options = options)
driver_new.get(url)
```

[image]

Comment: `sleep()` for few seconds

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

[image: cloudflare]

...implies that the [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) have detected your requests to the website as an automated bot and subsequently denying you the access to the application.

---

### Solution

In these cases the a potential solution would be to use the [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) to initialize the *Chrome Browsing Context*.

[undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) is an optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io. It automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

- Code Block:

  ```
  import undetected_chromedriver as uc
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get('https://bet365.com')
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium app redirect to Cloudflare page when hosted on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842858/selenium-app-redirect-to-cloudflare-page-when-hosted-on-heroku/64960149#64960149)
- [How to bypass being rate limited ..HTML Error 1015 using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128879/how-to-bypass-being-rate-limited-html-error-1015-using-python/65136081#65136081)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still "Checking...", even with the code block that you have suggested. Could it be that the website, which I am trying to connect to has foreseen this?

Comment: @KamranAbbasov Possibly your _IP_ got blacklisted. Check the first reference link to whitelist your IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`time.sleep(6)`
That should be enough if you are redirected after 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Java so it is different then Python.

Comment: The thing is it is much longer (indefinitely) longer then 5 seconds...