# Disable selenium driver detection on geckodriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'd like to know if the method shared here: [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904) it's still currently working and if yes I'd like to know how to do the same using Java on geckodriver.

Since now I tried the following without success:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled","False");
    profile.setPreference("useAutomationExtension","False");
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProfile(profile);

    String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/" + user + "/Desktop/Configs/geckodriver");
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.executeScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})");


    driver.get("https://mysite/");
```

But typing `navigator.webdriver` in console still returns `True`