# Selenium can't open a second page

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using Selenium to open different pages of a site. Have tried multiple times but the browser does not open a second webpage after the initial GET call. Have tried on both Chrome and Safari. Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-2")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-3")
```

Here is the error I get for the second call:

[image]

The info from Network logs is Error 504, but I have verified that it works perfectly when done on another window of the browser, without automation

Comment: It looks like the page DOES open it's just opened with an errror from the webserver.

Comment: Yes, it is a server error, but no more clues to help resolve the same. The same is fine for some other 2 sites

Comment: I wonder if there is more to the URL action than a simple GET is providing.  Are you sure that is the correct and full URL? Can you execute this manually? What does the network tab in the browser say is happening when run manually?

Comment: The code worked perfectly fine for me. I used Chrome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of more information about your usecase would have helped to construct a more canonical answer. However I was able to access the [Page 2 of justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services](https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-2) with a minimized code block as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-2")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: justdial]

But while sending multiple `get()` one after another:

```
driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-2")
driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-3")
```

It seems [ChromeDriver initiated *Chrome Browser* gets detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191) and the following error is shown:

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #97.e5732c31.1612205693.6fd2708
```

---

### Solution

To avoid the detection you can add the following option:

```
--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled
```

---

### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-2")
driver.get("https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-3")
```

Comment: it seems that nowadays (2023) use more complex detection and `start-maximized` and `--disabled-blink-features=AutomationControlled` alone it's not enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
options.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(
    "https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-2")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get(
    "https://www.justdial.com/Chennai/Hr-Consultancy-Services/nct-10258625/page-3")
```

the website is detecting automation use above code :)

**You can also do this in single line**

Just add below argument:

```
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

disabling enable-automation , or disabling automation controller disables webdriver.navigator which few websites uses to detect automation scripts