# How to use undetected_chromedriver.v2 in kali linux

Tags: selenium, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver, kali-linux, undetected-chromedriver

How to use undetected_chromedriver.v2 in kali linux

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
options = uc.ChromeOptions()

# setting profile
options.user_data_dir = "c:\\temp\\profile"

# another way to set profile is the below (which takes precedence if both variants are used
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=c:\\temp\\profile2')

# just some options passing in to skip annoying popups
options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
bw = uc.Chrome(options=options, version_main=92)
```

Comment: how to change the path in for kali linux

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) then using [*undetected_chromedriver.v2*](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver#the-version-2-way) you will face an error as:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

which is inline as per the status:

> July 2021: Currently busy implementing selenium 4 for undetected-chromedriver

---

However with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) you can still use the [*undetected_chromedriver v1*](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver#datadomeco-example--v1-old-stuff) as follows:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = uc.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('https://datadome.co/customers-stories/toppreise-ends-web-scraping-and-content-theft-with-datadome/')
driver.save_screenshot('datadome_undetected_webddriver.png')
```

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Undetected Chromedriver not loading correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65529808/undetected-chromedriver-not-loading-correctly/65534593#65534593)
- [Evade detection of selenium automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66199053/evade-detection-of-selenium-automation/66200459#66200459)