# Accesssing Corsair.com with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to access https://www.corsair.com/ with Selenium in Python without getting blocked by Corsair?

When I try to load the page in Selenium, it keeps giving me this error message:
[image: Error when loading the Corsair website with Selenium]

What I tried to bypass it, is changing the user-agent to a random one, which didn't fix the issue.

**This is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)

print('Loading Corsair Website ...')
driver.get("https://www.corsair.com/")
```

Comment: on my initial run, it worked, but after subsequent runs, their website somehow detects that it's automated software. Usually modifying the User-Agent helped me in those cases.

Comment: @GevorgChobanyan Yes when I first tried it, it worked as well, but after multiple tries, it didn't. Did you try using my code with the random User-Agent? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to evade detection of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) automation and one of them is to use the following argument:

- [--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66199053/evade-detection-of-selenium-automation/66200459#66200459).

Code Block:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
# options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.corsair.com/")
driver.save_screenshot("image.png")
```

Screenshot:

[image: image.png]

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error message. I didn't do it with Service tho

Comment: @AndreSolbach Using or not using _Service_ shouldn't matter. I've been successfully hitting the url 5 times in succession without any issues.