# How not to be detected by browser using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to access a site that is asking to verify that it is human accessing the site the tool used by the site is cloudflare

I use the user-agent to access the sites and so far I haven't had any problems, but with the current site I'm facing this barrier and there's a detail I configured a 100 second sleep to do the recognition manually and even so the site recognizes that webdrive is a robot.

`options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"')`

Comment: There were some attempts to bypass cloudflare (and maybe are successful, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518406/how-to-bypass-cloudflare-browser-checking-selenium-python)), but the process is still painful and should not be considered as reliable for automating purposes

Comment: Okay, you look into it, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) pip package which is designed to be undetected to the most of antibot services:

> Optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot
> services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io
> Automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

Comment: Thanks at first everything went well, this library works on the systematic table of selenium basic from what I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing your public IP address would work. I had this issue before and struggled with headers and drivers.
But this varied from website to website though.

Comment: I believe this does not work, as they detect that the connection is made through an optimized browser.