# Download a pdf url using Python

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I am trying to download a .pdf url from this website
[PDFLINK](https://www.cell.com/heliyon/pdf/S2405-8440(18)33206-7.pdf)
https://www.cell.com/heliyon/pdf/S2405-8440(18)33206-7.pdf
I am able to view it from my browser, but using the requests with Python won't let me download it.

I tried the following, but I was not able to get it to download properly. It would return a 403 or say that the .pdf is corrupted. But I can view the link fine https://www.cell.com/heliyon/pdf/S2405-8440(18)33206-7.pdf
Any ideas?

```
import requests


def download_pdf(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    with open('sample.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://www.cell.com/heliyon/pdf/S2405-8440(18)33206-7.pdf"
    download_pdf(url)
```

Comment: If we change the output file to `sample.txt` we can see what the problem is. The output file looks like this (https://pastebin.com/h8VyqWUu). This is probably because the site has some functionality to prevent programmatic access to the file. I couldn't figure out how to bypass it, but I'll give it another go tomorrow. Until then if someone can beat me, awesome!

Comment: Please see comments below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll explain how I figured this out to help your understanding:

I used the 'Network' tab in my browser's (Chrome) devtools to find the successful request that is sent to the server by my browser. This is the request that allows you to successfully access the file, as opposed to the request sent from the python script which doesn't effectively download the file, and rather returns http error code [403 - Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) (Note: as far as I'm concerned, this is obviously the website indicating that downloading the file this way is forbidden).

I looked into the request headers and added one to the `headers` argument of `request.get()`. This gave me a successful http status code of [200 - OK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200). I continued to remove headers until finding the minimum set of headers needed, which are "Cookie" and "User-Agent". If you copy those headers into the `headers` (headers is a dictionary) argument of `request.get()` it will work

That said, you will need to copy the values for the User-Agent and Cookies out of your browser's devtools. The cookies also change over time, so you'll need to use the browser anyway to get up-to-date values for your request. Either that, or you'll need to really dig deep into how the site works and reverse engineer their cookie generation, if that's even possible. I'd advise against pursuing it too much further, as in my opinion the site is indicating that they don't want you downloading files programmatically like this.

### Where to go from here

Apparently every paper in the Heliyon collection, which is the collection your example pdf is in, is also [hosted on ScienceDirect](https://www.cell.com/heliyon/aims-and-scope):

> Every published article will be immediately available on both cell.com/heliyon and ScienceDirect and will be indexed by PubMed, Scopus, Web of Science™ and Science Citation Index Expanded™ (SCIE), ensuring that it reaches the widest possible audience. Heliyon's impact factor is 4.0 as of June 2023.

Elsevier, which runs ScienceDirect, has a [free-to-use API](https://dev.elsevier.com/sciencedirect.html#!/Article_Retrieval/ArticleRetrieval) with which you can easily download articles, including the one you are trying to download, with just the [doi](https://www.doi.org/) and your API key. I've put together an extremely simple script below that you can use once you've [registered for the Elsevier API](https://dev.elsevier.com/apikey/manage) and created your own api key:

```
api_template = 'https://api.elsevier.com/content/article/doi/{doi}?apiKey={api_key}&httpAccept={http_accept}'

doi = '10.1016/j.heliyon.2018.e00938'
api_key = '<your_api_key>'
http_accept = 'application/pdf'

uri = api_template.format(doi=doi, api_key=api_key, http_accept=http_accept)
res = requests.get(uri)
with open('out.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

I've not included things like error handling, or even wrapping this in a function, but this should get you started. Best of luck!

Comment: Amazing response! This works for me. Thank you for your detailed input!

Answer (score 1):

Many academic publishers implement anti-scraping measures on their websites, complicating the task of downloading PDFs using the `requests` library. Even employing `headers` to mimic a browser session does not guarantee success in bypassing these measures. `SeleniumBase` is a framework designed for browser automation and testing, building upon `Selenium`. Its undetected Chrome driver offers improved evasion of anti-scraping detection, more closely mimicking human browser interactions, though it is slower than the standard Chrome driver. This method, illustrated below, can facilitate most download tasks. **However, it is crucial to use it responsibly and not for abusive purposes.**

```
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True, external_pdf = True)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

I have also performed tests in Google Colab, which successfully retrieved resources. Nonetheless, additional testing might be necessary for compatibility with different operating systems.

Ref:

[How to bypass cloudflare browser checking selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518406/how-to-bypass-cloudflare-browser-checking-selenium-python)

[Github SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Hey thanks for your response also. This also worked, but I am unsure if this method would work on a Virtual machine without a browser installed. I tried it on a Windows 11 machine with chrome installed and it installed and downloaded, but unsure whether it would work as programmatically as the code above. Still a great method to use. Thanks!

Comment: Additional explanations have been provided. I just want to make some contributions to the community and upvote those answers that provide help for me. :: )