# Udemy website keeps on loading while trying to Web Scrape with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I am starting to learn about web scraping. For practice, I am trying to get a list with all the courses name that appears in this query: "https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=api+python" the problem is when I start the script the web does not load en eventually the windows get closed. I think maybe Udemy has some type of security for automations

[image]

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

website = "https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=api+python"
path = "/"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options);  
driver.get(website)
time.sleep(5) 
matches = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=api+python) website not loading completely may be due to the fact that Selenium driven [ChromeDriver initiated *Chrome Browser* gets detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447) as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) and further navigation is getting blocked.

---

### Solution

An easier hack to evade the detection would be to add the following argument:

- [`--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66200459/7429447)

So effectively your code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=api+python')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[contains(., 'results for')]")))
driver.save_screenshot("udemy.png")
```

Saved Screenshot:

[image: udemy.png]

Comment: Got this error on the driver line: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

Comment: @AlbinRdz This is [tag:selenium4] based solution. With [tag:selenium3] you will see this error.