# How to evade blocking by Walmart using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

I am learning python, I have done some bots (nothing special), I am trying to create a new one on walmart, but when I launch chromedriver, walmart site ask me for solve a captcha, this is not a problem, because I can solve it manually. The problem is that everytime I solve the captcha, the captcha appears again. My bot requires that I log in in walmart site, so I tested google chrome (not chromedriver) and I can login without any problem. I thought could be my ip or something else, but after some tests I realized that walmart block the log in process if I use chromedriver.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\PCHOME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped1\\Default\\gdps");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'dchrome\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/")
```

In this case I am trying to log in manually (I tried to do with bot already). The site loads well, but the captcha does not allow me to log in, it just appears and appears and appears...
this is the captcha img:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0AxV.jpg]

I press and hold the button until teh captcha is cleared, then appears this symbol ✓  and then appears the captcha again.
Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Have u found an answer to this, cause i'm running into similar problems?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To avoid getting blocked being detected as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* you need to use the argument [*`--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994908/selenium-cant-open-a-second-page/65998533#65998533) as follows:

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# Avoiding detection
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/")
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: walmart]

Comment: This doesn't prevent being detected and blocked for me.