# Web Scraping using pythn Jupyter Notebook

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web, screen-scraping, python-extensions

I have been attempting web scraping, but I encountered an error that states,
"We're sorry but default doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue."
I have tried enabling JavaScript by using chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript") in my Jupyter Notebook, but the error persists. I am looking for assistance from someone who has extensive experience in web scraping to help me resolve this issue.

any one worked on web scraping?

Comment: Please try the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186343/we-re-sorry-but-our-site-doesn-t-work-properly-without-javascript-enabled-pleas).