# Specific sites doesn't render using Selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using selenium with python on both Chrome and Firefox. This specific website stays blank on both browsers when I try to run it with selenium - I'd appreciate any help. Here's my code for chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])
    
    path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, chrome_options=options)
    
    driver.get('https://main.knesset.gov.il/Activity/committees/pages/allcommitteesagenda.aspx')
```

Comment: some pages are protected against scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the argument [***--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66199053/evade-detection-of-selenium-automation/66200459#66200459)

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
  driver.get("https://main.knesset.gov.il/Activity/committees/pages/allcommitteesagenda.aspx")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: main_knesset_gov_il]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to evade blocking by Walmart using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70072537/how-to-evade-blocking-by-walmart-using-selenium-webdriver/70073393#70073393)
- [Selenium can't open a second page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994908/selenium-cant-open-a-second-page/65998533#65998533)