# Problem connecting to websites from Google Cloud VM instances (via Selenium or curl)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform

Today I came across this problem.

I am developing a Python script that uses Selenium to read a website. This script is running inside a gc instance. This usually works fine but this time I got blocked with the following message:

> Javascript disabled

> Javascript is needed to run Uber Eats. You can try enabling it or visiting the website with a browser that supports Javascript.

My gc instance is a Debian OS webserver and it has a static IP reserved for it.

I think the problem is not related to Selenium/Chrome webdriver configuration because if a do curl " xxx.com " from the terminal, I got the same response as in the script. Moreover, the script works running it from my local computer, thus I think the javascript error msg is misleading.

I read that some websites do not accept dynamic IP connections and that Google instances use a pool of dynamic IP's to outbound connections.

Could this be the reason? Is there anything I can try?

Comment: Are you sure your vms network is configured correctly (such that external access is allowed)?

Comment: I am not completely sure. It is a regular VM GCP instance running Debian. I reserved a static IP and open the ports (80,8080,5432) since it is a webserver and this IP is used to inbound connection. I think connecting from the server to the world would be straightforward with this configuration. I am not sure if GCP IP's are blacklisted by some services or if the problem is that the outbound IP being used is from a pool of dynamic IP's and the service do not allow connections from dynamic IP's. I am just wondering all those things. Please, point me to the correct direction.

Comment: Search for other answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70201673/8016720