# selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot redefine property: webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-remotedriver

I am executing the following script in Selenium Remotedriver and getting an error:

```
 self.driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
```

The idea behind the code is to hide the webdriver parameter

The error is the following:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot redefine property: webdriver
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

I am using this question as a reference: [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec)

I am using python, not Java, however this line of code looks like the way I wrote on python