# Insert userID and Password with selenium

Tags: pandas, selenium-webdriver, passwords, userid

I am connecting with Python to the following webpage

https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fsd/fsf#!/files

I have written the following Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

if True:
    chromedriver_path = r"./driver/chromedriver"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
    url = "https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fsd/fsf#!/files"

    browser.get(url)
    escolhe = browser.find_element("xpath", topics_xpath)
    time.sleep(10)
    escolhe.click()
    time.sleep(60)
    browser.close()
```

The web page opens up and I am prompted to enter the user ID (which is my e-mail address).

[image]

**Question 1. How do I enter the password and click on Next from Python?**

After I will have managed to do that, I will prompted to enter my password and to click on Next.

**Question 2. How do I enter my password and click on Next from Python?**

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write some codes to finish it.
because I have no account, so you should finish type password by yourself.
**"send_keys"** is typing your account
**"WebDriverWait"** is **wait** **until** next can be clicked
**"click"** is to click the button of **next**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import os
def edgeopen(driverpath):
    service=Service(executable_path=driverpath)
    edge_options = EdgeOptions()
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec
    edge_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
    edge_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    edge_options.add_argument('lang=zh-CN,zh,zh-TW,en-US,en')
    # edge_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    edge_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    # edge_options.add_argument('start-maxmized')
    edge_options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")#就是这一行告诉chrome去掉了webdriver痕迹
    
    edge_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options, service = service)
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
    driver.set_script_timeout(130)
    
    return driver

def fillnamepassword(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, r"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/input").send_keys("username@gmail.com")
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, r"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/button")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/button").click()
    time.sleep(130)

def login():
    website = r'https://ecas.ec.europa.eu/cas/login'
    driverpath = r'C:\Users\10696\Desktop\csdn\edgedriver'
    driver = edgeopen(driverpath)
    driver.get(website)
    fillnamepassword(driver)
    driver.quit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    login()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using send_keys:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


username = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='username']"))
)
username.send_keys("your username")
username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the [website](https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fsd/fsf#!/files) to send a character sequence within the *unique identifier* field and move to the *password* field ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fsd/fsf#!/files")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("Giampaolo Levorato" +Keys.ENTER)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fsd/fsf#!/files")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("Giampaolo Levorato" +Keys.ENTER)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: EULogin]